# Not able to execute more than one command using plink.exe

Tags: python, plink

I have a python script for connecting to remote host and do telnet then execute command. My python script having below line

```
os.system("plink.exe -ssh -pw PASSWORD USER@IP_ADDRESS 'telnet 0 XXXX;','LT_START;'")
```

It will connect to remote server (`IP_ADDRESS`) and it will execute first command (`telnet 0 XXXX;`) then it won't execute 2nd command (`LT_START;`).

I can keep both the commands in text file and run, but my requirement is I should pass commands as mentioned in the command (Do not pass commands through any file).

Please help me on this. I have spent 3 days for this. any help much appreciated.

If I'm not clear please let me know.

Comment: @Rahn: Thanks for the info. Could you please suggest me the alternative method if any?

Comment: Sorry, I just do the formatting. I'm not familiar with `plink`.